# Can´t save files using ftp on genexus

Tags: ftp, ibm-midrange, genexus

I am trying to save a file on a library inside a Iseries database using the GxFtpPut on genexus 10 V3 with .net  but when sending the file genexus tries to send it to a windows directory instead of sending it to the library which  works using the ftp command on the cmd

I've already tried to changing the route is using to no avail and trying to find another way of sending the file through genexus.

for example when using the cmd I just put this :

`put C:\FILES\Filename.txt Library/Filename`

And it works on sending the file  inside the library,

but when doing this on genexus:

`Call("GxFtpPut", &FileDirectory , 'Library/'+&FileName,'B' )`

Does not work and tries to find a directory with that name inside the windows files of the server

I just want to be able to send it to the server library without issue.

Comment: What is the error

Comment: Given that IBM i is an EBCDIC environment, if you transfer an ASCII (.txt) file in binary mode (B), you are unlikely to be able to read it on the IBM i side. If you set the transfer mode to ASCII (A), it may go ahead and convert the text to EBCDIC.

Answer (score 1):

IBM i has two distinct name formats depending on the file system you are trying to use. NAMEFMT 0 is the `library/filename` format, and is likely unknown to PC FTP clients. NAMEFMT 1 is the typical hierarchical directory path used by non-IBM i computers, and also works with IBM i if you want to put a file anywhere in the IFS (Integrated File System).

Fun fact, the native library file system is also accessible from the IFS. But to address it you need to use a format that might be a little unfamiliar. `/QSYS.lib/library.lib/filename.file/membername.mbr` You may be able to drop the member name.

To change name format, you can issue the SITE sub-command on your remote host like this:

```
QUOTE SITE NAMEFMT 0    -- This sets name format 0 (library/filename)
QUITE SITE NAMEFMT 1    -- This sets name format 1 (directory path)
```

---

I did some testing with a plain Windows FTP client. The test file on the PC was a text file created in Notepad++. Turns out that we start out in NAMEFMT 0 unless it is changed. It looks like genexus only supports a limited set of commands. So here is the limited FTP script that works:

```
ascii
put test.txt mylib/testpf
```

I can now pull up `testpf` on the greenscreen utilities and read it. I can also read `testpf` in my GUI SQL client. The ASCII text has been converted properly to EBCDIC.

```
|TESTPF                                                                          |
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|                                                                                |
|// ------------------------------------                                         |
|// Sweep                                                                        |
|//                                                                              |
|// Performs the sweep logic                                                     |
|// ------------------------------------                                         |
|dcl-proc Sweep;                                                                 |
|                                                                                |
|                                                                                |
|  exec sql                                                                      |
|    update atty a                                                               |
|      set ymglsb = (select ymglsb from glaty                                    |
|                    where atty = a.atty)                                        |
|      where atty in (select atty from glaty where atty = a.atty);               |
|//    where ymglsb in (select ymglsb from glaty where atty = a.atty);           |
|  if %subst(sqlstate: 1: 2) < '00' or                                           |
|      %subst(sqlstate: 1: 2) > '02';                                            |
|    exec sql get diagnostics condition 1                                        |
|      :message = message_text;                                                  |
|    SendSqlMsg('02: ' + message);                                               |
|  endif;                                                                        |
|                                                                                |
|  exec sql                                                                      |
|    update atty a                                                               |
|      set ymglsb = '000'                                                        |
|      where not exists (select * from glaty where atty = a.atty);               |
|  if %subst(sqlstate: 1: 2) < '00' or                                           |
|      %subst(sqlstate: 1: 2) > '02';                                            |
|    exec sql get diagnostics condition 1                                        |
|      :message = message_text;                                                  |
|    SendSqlMsg('03: ' + message);                                               |
|  endif;                                                                        |
|                                                                                |
|end-proc;                                                                       |
```

However, if I try to transfer in binary mode, the resulting data in the file looks like this:

```
|TESTPF                                                                          |
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|ëÏÁÁø&ÁÊÃ?Ê_ËÈÇÁËÏÁÁø%    |
|?ÅÑÄÀÄ%øÊ?ÄëÏÁÁøÁÌÁÄËÉ%      |
|ÍøÀ/ÈÁ/ÈÈ`/ËÁÈ`_Å%ËÂËÁ%ÁÄÈ`_Å%ËÂÃÊ?_Å%/È`  |
|ÏÇÁÊÁ/ÈÈ`//ÈÈ`ÏÇÁÊÁ/ÈÈ`Ñ>ËÁ%ÁÄÈ/ÈÈ`ÃÊ?_Å%/È`ÏÇÁÊÁ/ÈÈ |
|`//ÈÈ`ÏÇÁÊÁ`_Å%ËÂÑ>ËÁ%ÁÄÈ`_Å%ËÂÃÊ?_Å%/È`ÏÇÁÊÁ/ÈÈ`//ÈÈ |
|`ÑÃ¶ËÍÂËÈËÉ%ËÈ/ÈÁ?Ê¶ËÍÂËÈËÉ%ËÈ/ÈÁ  |
|ÁÌÁÄËÉ%ÅÁÈÀÑ/Å>?ËÈÑÄËÄ?>ÀÑÈÑ?>_ÁËË/ÅÁ_ÁËË/ÅÁ¬ÈÁÌÈ   |
|ëÁ>ÀëÉ%(ËÅ_ÁËË/ÅÁÁ>ÀÑÃÁÌÁÄËÉ%ÍøÀ/ÈÁ/ÈÈ`/     |
|ËÁÈ`_Å%ËÂÏÇÁÊÁ>?ÈÁÌÑËÈËËÁ%ÁÄÈÃÊ?_Å%/È`ÏÇÁÊÁ/ÈÈ`// |
|ÈÈ`ÑÃ¶ËÍÂËÈËÉ%ËÈ/ÈÁ?Ê¶ËÍÂËÈËÉ%ËÈ/ÈÁ  |
|ÁÌÁÄËÉ%ÅÁÈÀÑ/Å>?ËÈÑÄËÄ?>ÀÑÈÑ?>_ÁËË/ÅÁ_ÁËË/ÅÁ¬ÈÁÌÈ   |
|ëÁ>ÀëÉ%(ËÅ_ÁËË/ÅÁÁ>ÀÑÃÁ>ÀøÊ?Ä                             |
```

This has not been converted because we have told IBM i FTP server not to convert to EBCDIC because it is binary.

So try ASCII mode, use the library/filename format. The target file does not need to pre-exist.

Comment: Thank you but this does not help me, it make me understand how this thing work, but what I want is to save the files inside the As400 using the ftp from genexus

Comment: I don't have genexus, so I can't give you code. I was just hoping that between your understanding of genexus, and my understanding of the IBM i FTP server, I could point you in the correct direction. Instead of trying the `library/filename` format, which doesn't work, maybe try the `/QSYS.lib/library.lib/filename.file` format. Just replace `library` and `filename` with your library and filename. make sure you keep the `.lib` and `.file` extenders as they are object types, and important to the name format.

Comment: Thank you, I already try that but it didn't work,   I don't know what is the problem because it should, it might be something to do With the way that genexus handle the route of the library